# How to import mocked data from shell command

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using request mock and getting json data from external file:

```
import { RequestMock } from 'testcafe';
const mockData = require('abc.json');

var mock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo('https://api.mycorp.com/users/id/135865')
    .respond(mockData);

fixture `My fixture`
    .page `https://mycorp.com`
    .requestHooks(mock);

test('My test', async t => { /* ... */ });
```

Now, i am trying to import mockData from my storage system.
Let's say, CLI command to pull abc.json into current directory is:

```
mysystem pull abc.json
```

I am looking for code to do so. I tried using child_process but my CLI command many take few seconds to fetch abc.json and meanwhile testcafe code executes.

```
import { RequestMock } from 'testcafe';

const getData = require('child_process').exec;
getData('mysystem pull abc.json', (e, stdout, stderr)=> {
    if (e instanceof Error) {
        console.error(e);
        throw e;
    }
    console.log('stdout ', stdout);
    console.log('stderr ', stderr);
});
const mockData = require('./abc.json');
    
    var mock = RequestMock()
        .onRequestTo('https://api.mycorp.com/users/id/135865')
        .respond(mockData);
    
    fixture `My fixture`
        .page `https://mycorp.com`
        .requestHooks(mock);
    
    test('My test', async t => { /* ... */ });
```

I am getting error, that

```
mock is not defined.
```

I can clearly see that my json gets loaded once testcafe execution finishes.
So, i need a way for shell command to finish first and then testcafe code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe allows you to create asynchronous functions to mock your data.
Take a look at the following article: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requestmock/respond.html#a-custom-response-function.

You can modify your `getData` function to return Promise as follows:

```
function getData () {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        exec('your-api', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

In this case, you can modify your RequestMock so that it will work asynchronously:

```
var mock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo('your-api')
    .respond(async (req, res) => {
        const body = await getData();
        res.setBody(body);
    });
```